# Propagate uncertainty of a parameter through a function

Tags: uncertainty, distributions, error-propagation

Suppose I have a probability distribution (in fact I've got a nice case where that distribution is Gaussian) on a parameter value. e.g. the parameter $x$ has $\mu = 3$ and $\sigma^2 = 1$.

Now suppose that the value of $x$ is also used to determine the variance of a new (Gaussian) distribution - $\sigma^2_{new} = f(x)$ (in my case $f(x)$ is linear in $x$ so it's a nice function - it's something like $\sigma^2_{new} = a(1-x)$ where $a$ is a known constant).

My question is how do I incorporate the probability distribution (my uncertainty) of $x$ to more accurately reflect the uncertainty (in my case, the variance) of the new distribution?

Secondary question to that - How do I do the same thing but when $\sigma^2_{new} = f(x)$ is no longer linear in $x$?

Comment: Can't work.  X would have a range of $-\infty, \infty$, so would give negative $\sigma^2_{new}$ values, which would be invalid.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I need to rethink the probability distribution of x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a particular case of conditional distributions: if $x\sim P(x)$ and $y|x\sim Q(y|x)$, then$$y\sim\int \text{d}P(x) Q(y|x)$$In your setting, if $y|x\sim \mathcal{N}(y;\mu_y,\sigma_y^2(x))$ and $x\sim \mathcal{N}(x;\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)$ then $$y\sim\int \mathcal{N}(y;\mu_y,\sigma_y^2(x)) \mathcal{N}(x;\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)\text{d}x$$
As pointed out by [AlaskaRon](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/85903/alaskaron), it is not possible that $\sigma_y^2(x)=a(1-x)$ when $x$ is Gaussian, since $(1-x)$ has a positive probability of being negative.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it. I had come across the negative value pitfall so I realised I needed to restrict the domain/rethink the distribution of x